# why does cookie.domain set two cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I'm trying to get a subdomain to create a cookie for the entire domain instead of just its subdomian using the property cookie.domain, so the two subdomains can share the cookie info.  When I deploy to IIS I get 2 cookies created, one for the domain and another for the subdomain.  Why is that?  When I update the cookie the only one that gets updated is the subdomain one, rendering the domain cookie kind of useless.

I tried to trace this through my code, but running visual studio in debug mode doesn't actually set any cookie at all, unless I don't set the cookie.domain property.  Leaving domain.cookie out I get a cookie set to localhost, but only that one cookie.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Showing us some actual code might help us diagnose the problem more easily.

Comment: Too true, but I wasn't sure which code might be responsible, and though perhaps the creation of the two cookies was a default behavior somehow.  See my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I finally answered my own quesion(s).  I'll tackle the second one first, about running the site in debug mode:

Visual studio debugs to the site http://localhost:[someport].  So if the code is set to create a cookie using cookie.domain for mydomain.com, the cookie isn't set because the browser knows you're at localhost instead of the domain specified.  To remedy this I put an entry in my hosts file so that mydomain.com is pointed to 127.0.0.1.  Then I fired up the site in debug mode.  When the site came up as localhost I changed the URL in the browswer to http://subdomain.domain.com:[someport] and refreshed.  Now the cookie can be set.

Doing this helped me trace through my code to find the issue of two cookies being created by my subdomain website.  What I found is that the mydomain.com cookie was being created okay (CreateCookie method below) because of cookie.domain.  However, when I was trying to update the expiration on the cookie (UpdateCookie below) it reverted back to thinking it should be using the subdomain cookie and went ahead and created it when it didn't find one.  All I had to do was set cookie.domain again before setting the cookie and updating the expiration.  Now I only have one cookie.

```
public void CreateCookie()
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(mConfig.webCookie);
    TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0);
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now; ;

    cookie["Username"] = mEncrypt.Encrypt(mUser.Username);
    cookie.Domain = "mydomian.com";

    cookie.Expires = time + span;

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}

public void UpdateCookie()
{ 
    TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0);
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[mConfig.webCookie];

    // without specifying the domain the cookie will be set with the subdomain
    cookie.Domain = "mydomain.com";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[mConfig.webCookie].Expires = time + span;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set this cookie name for the full domain and subdomain on `web.config` on `httpCookies`

```
<httpCookies domain="domain.com" httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="false" />
```

set domain.com and NOT www.domain.com to archive what you say, to have the same cookie on domain and sub domain. Similar there is a parameter on authentication that you set this cookie settings, depend for what cookie you talking about.

In your question "why is that?" the answer is that if you not set this parameters for the cookies then the cookies actually use the current host name, so they are different if the first name of the sub-domain change.

Comment: I tried this by commenting out my cookie.domain lines in my solution below, and adding the httpCookies to web.config.  I still get two cookies created, one for the domain and another for the subdomain.